# How can i extract and combine inline css style properties

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I read a couple of answers and all of them seems to assume you have a single object containing `CSS` instead of single properties, I tried the answers and I couldn't make it work, I was wondering what's wrong and what's the best way to do this, here is what I have done so far :

```
import React from 'react';
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel';

const label = (props) => {
    // <label onClick={props.onClick} className={props.className + ' ' + props.gridClass} style={props.inlineStyle} >{props.label}</label>
    let divStyleArray = [];

    if (typeof props.inlineStyle.background !== 'undefined') {        
        divStyleArray.push(props.inlineStyle.background)
        delete props.inlineStyle.background
    }

    if (typeof props.inlineStyle.textAlign !== 'undefined') {
        divStyleArray.push(props.inlineStyle.textAlign)
        delete props.inlineStyle.textAlign
    }

    const customStyle = {
        width: '100%'
    }

    const divStyle = Object.assign({}, ...divStyleArray);

    return (
        <div className={props.gridClass} style={{divStyle}}>
            <FormLabel component="label" onClick={props.onClick} style={{ ...customStyle, ...props.inlineStyle }}>{props.label}</FormLabel>
        </div>
    )
}


export default label;
```

My goal is to extract a couple of `CSS` property, give it to the `div` and then give the rest to whats inside the `div`
**Update 01:**
I tried the answered given but it doesn't seem to work properly, here is what i did:

```
import React from 'react';
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel';

const label = (props) => {
    let inlineStyle = {
        ...props.inlineStyle
    }

    const divStyle = {
        background: inlineStyle.background,
        textAlign: inlineStyle.textAlign,
    }

    delete inlineStyle.background;
    delete inlineStyle.textAlign;

    const customStyle = {
        width: '100%'
    }    

    return (
        <div className={props.gridClass} style={divStyle}>
            <FormLabel component="label" onClick={props.onClick} style={{ ...customStyle, ...inlineStyle }}>{props.label}</FormLabel>
        </div>
    )
}

export default label;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all deleting stuff from the props object would be anti-pattern, or at least bad practice as far as I know.

If you only need the two properties you use there you could use this code:

```
const label = (props) => {
    let divStyle = {
        background: props.background,
        textAlign: props.textAlign,
    };

    const customStyle = {
        width: '100%'
    }
    return (
        <div className={props.gridClass} style={{divStyle}}>
            <FormLabel
                component="label"
                onClick={props.onClick}
                style={{
                  ...customStyle,
                  ...props.inlineStyle,
                  background: undefined,
                  textAlign: undefined,
                }}
            >{props.label}</FormLabel>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: The `props.background` or `textAlign` can be undefined, wont that cause a problem?

Comment: No because then these two properties would be set to undefined in the divStyle object and then get ignored when in the style prop of the div element since they're unset.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't had the chance to try your answer sooner, i did it today and it doesn't seem to work properly, i updated the question with the new code i wrote, please take a look and see whats wrong, thank you.

Comment: Can you please check `Update 01` and see why your answer doesn't work ?, i will really appreciate it if you could do this,  i will also accept your answer, thank you.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned the code in Update 01 should work, but there might also be an css unstading issue. If you set the background color for the surrounding div the form label gets the same background color if not background color is set for it.